# How to understand load_resource and authorize_resource methods of cancancan gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancancan

I am using the cancancan gem in my rails application. But I am not much clear for the meaning of `load_and_authorize_resource` method. I know this is the same as calling `load_resource` and `authorize_resource`.

`load_resource` will create a new instance of a model, or get a instance by `params[:id]`, or a collection of instances, then `authorize_resource` method will use these instances to authorize. But if I already have a `Model.find(params[:id])` or `Model.new` in each controller action, dose I need to add `load_resource` method?

For some action（Non RESTful actions) , they don't have relationship with model, so I don't need to get a instance, for this situation, `authorize_resource` how to work normally?

Any idea is appreciate! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `load_and_authorize_resource` sets a `before_filter` for each action to load the resource into an instance variable and authorize it automatically. So this is useful for RESTful actions. Now if you have Non RESTful actions in the same controller which can't load the resource you can do:

```
load_and_authorize_resource only: [:index, :show]
```

OR

```
skip_load_resource only: :new
```

This will skip the `before_filter` for those actions.

And if you have `Model.find(params[:id])` in controller either you can remove that or just use:

```
authorize_resource
```

You will not need the `load_resource` for these actions. The `load_resource` also does the same thing which you have done manually. It just adds a `before_action` to all the actions and finds the object according to `id`.

And the `load_resource` will always provide you the instance variable with the same name of `Model`, so if you are using something different in your views for you object then it won't help too. So choosing an option will depend on you and your code.

**Cancancan Wiki:**

> As of CanCan 1.5 you can use the `skip_load_and_authorize_resource`, `skip_load_resource` or `skip_authorize_resource` methods to skip any of the applied behaviour and specify specific actions like in a before filter.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If I skip authorize_resource for `new` action, anyone can access this API, it is not what I want, how to solve this problem?

Comment: Oh sorry that should be `skip_load_resource`. I have updated the answer

Comment: Note that `load_and_authorize_resource` will actually load the model instance for non RESTful actions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65858725/5783745