# Does load_and_authorize_resource authorize every single action in a controller, or just RESTful ones?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, cancan, cancancan

**TL;DR**

Basically, do I have to manually call `authorize!` in controller actions that aren't one of the 7 RESTful defaults, or does `load_and_authorize_resource` still do that for me in those non-standard actions?

**Longer version:**

I generated a controller via `rails scaffold` and then added several custom actions that do some random other things.

At the top of the controller, I have `load_and_authorize_resource`, which I believe will call `authorize!` in each of the actions.

Does it do that for *every single* action within the controller (including the custom ones), or *only* those that were generated by the scaffold? (i.e. [`index`, `show`, `new`, `edit`, `create`, `update`, `destroy`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-scaffolding.htm))

I see from the [cancancan docs](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan#32-loaders):

> Setting this for every action can be tedious, therefore the `load_and_authorize_resource` method is provided to automatically authorize all actions in a RESTful style resource controller.

But I'm not sure if that's just the 7 originals or others the developer adds as well

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is **yes, it will apply to *all* actions in the controller**

From [cancancan docs on choosing actions](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/blob/develop/docs/Authorizing-controller-actions.md#choosing-actions):

> By default this will apply to every action in the controller even if it is not one of the 7 RESTful actions.